# Output Term Guid instead of Label using TaxonomyFieldControl

Tags: sharepoint-designer, taxonomy

In SharePoint Designer, I can output value of a Managed Metadata field of a Publishing Page using

```
<Taxonomy:TaxonomyFieldControl FieldName="MyCategory" runat="server"/>
```

Is there any way to output the Guid of the term/terms instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out a server-side way to get the TermId.

Using the field name appended with _0, you can use SharePointWebControls:FieldValue to output Taxonomy Field value including the TermId.

```
<SharePointWebControls:FieldValue FieldName="MyCategory_0" runat="server"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use that field to output the term/s and then use javascript/jQuery to pull the GUIDs from the TaxonomyHiddenList for each term. I've done something similar with other field types from my page layouts to get to other data (like for a lookup field).

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of this "workaround", so accepting this unless someone has found a way to do it without client side code.

Comment: I don't know of any other options without resorting to custom server side code/code behind. It'd be nice if the controls had an attribute that allowed you to specify the output format, like ID/Label/GUID.

Comment: Found solution and added it as answer.